# Does CSP require "use strict"

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

Do I have to use the `"use script"` directive when serving my code with [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) enabled?
I cannot find any reference that says it is enforced but many code examples have it. I don't know if it's just *best practice* or **required**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to use the "use script" directive when serving my code with Content Security Policy enabled?

No

> I cannot find any reference that says it is enforced

Exactly

> but many code examples have it. I don't know if it's just best practice or required?

`"use strict"` is good practise entirely independent of the use (or otherwise) of CSP.